# GTLDriveFile file.downloadUrl is nil ? How to download pdf/doc/docx files from GoogleDrive in App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This is what I am doing to fetch files from Googledrive, but I am getting GTLDriveFile's downloadUrl nil. I tried for "exportLinks" also, but that is again nil. Please suggest.

```
#pragma mark- Downloading GDrive Files

-(void)downloadGDriveFiles:(GTLDriveFile *)file{
   GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [self.service.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:file.downloadUrl];

    [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
        if (error == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Retrieved file content");
        }
        else
        {
            [self showAlert:@"" message:@"Unable to download this file"];
        }
    }];
}
```

Thanks !!